tkinter label doesn't display text
This code works as intended when run alone:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
myFrame = tk.Frame(root)
    
def actionTest():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    svTitle.set(filename)
    lblTitle.update()

svTitle = tk.StringVar()
lblTitle = tk.Label(myFrame, textvariable=svTitle) 
lblTitle.pack()

btnTest = tk.Button(myFrame, text="Test", command=actionTest)  
btnTest.pack() 

lblTitle.pack()
btnTest.pack()
myFrame.pack()

root.mainloop()

However, when the code is run within a bigger block of code, the label doesn't display or update text. Please help!
I've now tried some of the suggestions, and can't get things to work.  So here's an isolated example, and a description of the output.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

def actionQuit():
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()
def chooseFile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename( title="Choose File",filetypes=[("ORG files", "*.org")])
    svTest.set(filename)  
    
root = tk.Tk()
btnQuit = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=actionQuit)
btnQuit.pack()


svTest = tk.StringVar()
svTest.set("initial value")
print(svTest.get())

lblTest = tk.Label(root, text=svTest)
btnTest = tk.Button(root, text="Choose File", command=chooseFile)
lblTest.pack()
btnTest.pack()
root.mainloop()

The output.

printing svTest.get() writes out, as expected, "initial value"
The UI displays a small "Main" window
A button labeled "Quit"
A label displaying the text "PY_VAR0"
A button labled "Testt"
Clicking on the Quit Button, terminates the program
Clicking on the Test Button open a file selection dialog.
The text of the Test label remains "PY_VAR0" rather than path of the chosen file.

So the Test Label always display PY_VAR0
Yikes. any insight

Please be specific about "bigger block of code", and what behaviors you're witnessing, since simply saying that your "label doesn't display or update text", doesn't provide any context other than some generic tips we can provide.

Does your bigger block of code include more than one call to Tk()?  Non-working Vars are among the various problems that causes.

Most probably the bigger block of code has another instance of Tk().

Try using svTitle = tk.StringVar(master=root) instead

You have both btnTest.pack() and lblTitle.pack()  duplicated.

textvariable= is how a Label (or other widget) refers to a Var, not text= - that's for static text only.

Not sure about the whole "when the code is run within a bigger block of code" part, without any context...
But, some basic ways you can make sure your issue with the label not updating would be to:

Make sure you only have one mainloop() call and only one Tk() in the entire application, otherwise you will have unprecedented behavior from multiple invocations.

Ensure that your StringVar, svTitle, is accessible in the context where actionTest() is defined and used. If svTag or actionTest() are defined in a different scope in the larger application, that could cause issues.

Check if the update() method is necessary. In Tkinter, the label should automatically update when its StringVar changes. If lblTitle.update() is not working as expected, it might be unnecessary. Instead, ensure that the StringVar is correctly set.

Double-check the packing order and location of your widgets. Overlapping widgets or improper packing can make some widgets not appear. Also, ensure that lblTitle.pack() and btnTest are not packed multiple times unnecessarily, as in your sample code lblStage.pack() is called twice.

Make sure myFrame is correctly initialized and packed before adding widgets to it. Sometimes, frames or widgets are created but not properly displayed due to the order of packing or due to being obscured by other frames...


Last advice is to make your code robust, add error handling around parts of your code that might fail, such as the file dialog invocation. This can help in identifying if the issue is with the file selection or later in the update chain.
